# How to change TableAdapter select commandtext

Tags: c#, .net, database, vb.net

I have created a typed dataset with data adapters using the Visual Studio Wizard.
I have a instance of one of the table adapters in my form and I want to change its SelectCommandtext when form is loaded (OnFormLoad event).
Who could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically access the `CommandText` property of the object on `Form_Load`.

I.E

```
dataSource1.CommandText = "SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM table1 ...";
```

Comment: No I Work By Dataset AND TableAdapter